# How to model a multinomial dataset with multiple predictor variables?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, likelihood

I have a dataset of 4 behaviour types (nominal, non ordered, count data: **number of occurrences** cannot be split or merged further)and several predictor variables, like temperature, number of boats, tide height (numeric variables). I want to run a model to **predict the likelihood** of a behaviour to happen based on the predictor variables (e.g.: below 0 C Behav1 is more likely to happen, between 0-20 C Behav2 is likely and above 20 C Behav3). I know GLMs can work with multiple predictors, but they are binomial (presence/absence, yes/no), and I want to run a multinomial model, but it does not work. I need to run my analysis in **R** and I do not seem to find a model for my problem. Also, I lack statistical knowledge, so I can not think of alternative solutions, however I tried (for 4 months constantly). I would really appreciate any ideas about approaching this problem. Picture attached of how my database looks like.

[image]

Comment: If your $y$ were binary, would you use logistic regression? If so, the multiclass extension of logistic regression goes by *multinomial logistic regression*.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a multinomial logistic regression model.  These models are very easy to code in any programming language: both fitting the model and producing Wald, Likelihood, and Score tests for the inclusion of a set of covariates (or a general linear hypothesis).  For the amateur, you can use the ${\tt multinom}$ function in the ${\tt nnet}$ package since you are using ${\tt R}$.

Comment: I would just add that the package VGAM (https://rdrr.io/cran/VGAM/man/multinomial.html) proposes a more flexible function for this type of model.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys! However, I ran a multinomial logistic regression, but the problem is that it compares 3 of the behaviours to the 4th of them. I need to see if behaviours on their own differ from a baseline level, let's say "zero". And I couldn't reset that baseline to zero, so the model took behav1 as a baseline and checked how the other behaviours changed... that doesn't answer my question: is the likelihood of one behaviour (or more) higher/ lower when the environmental conditions change?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice guys! However, I ran a multinomial logistic regression, but the problem is that it compares 3 of the behaviours to the 4th of them. I need to see if behaviours on their own differ from a baseline level, let's say "zero". And I couldn't reset that baseline to zero, so the model took behav1 as a baseline and checked how the other behaviours changed... that doesn't answer my question: is the likelihood of one behaviour (or more) higher/ lower when the environmental conditions change?

Comment: Welcome to CV. This does not really answer the question. Please use the "comment" link when you are in this situation, the site works better this way and you increase your chance to get an answer. Thank you.